# How to programatically add post to Wordpress blog from outside in PHP

Tags: php, api, wordpress, blogs

I would like to add a post to my Wordpress based blog (my own hosting) from outside of this blog using PHP. In short terms i would like to do something like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/addPost.php

Adds example post to my blog and thats all i need. How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress implements a number of APIs to allow this: http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support

Answer (score 2):

In addition to xml-rpc support, you might be interested in the "Press This" functionality:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Press_This

Answer (score 1):

I've found this excellent guide (in english) which complements tomaszs answer:
http://djzone.im/2011/04/simple-xml-rpc-client-to-wordpress-made-easy/